# Как получить значение тега по атрибуту xml-файла на Java?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, xml

Есть такой-то файл (`application.xml`). Из него нужно получить строку

```
<Data key="TrialSerialNumber">911987057659283838047464</Data>
```

А из нее уже получить число `911987057659283838047464`.

Как это сделать на Java?

Comment: Читайте про парсинг `XML`, например через `DocumentBuilderFactory` в нем есть метод `getAttribute`.

Comment: Парсить xml регулярными выражениями не то, что не серьёзно, но даже ошибочно. Применяйте всякие приёмы, специально придуманные для работы с xml.

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее правильно воспользоваться XPath выражением:

```
    import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

    import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
    import java.io.FileReader;

    public class XPathTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("D:\\programmer\\application.xml")) {
                XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
                String data =
                        xPath.evaluate(
                                "/Configuration/Other[@adobeCode='V7{}Photoshop-19-Win-GM']/Data[@key='TrialSerialNumber']",
                                new InputSource(fileReader)
                        );
                System.out.println(data);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать XPath, то лучше использовать эту строку кода вот с таким локатором:

```
xPath.evaluate("//Data[@key='TrialSerialNumber']", new InputSource(fileReader));
```

т.к. в данном случае атрибут `key='TrialSerialNumber'` является уникальным.

Узел

```
 <Data key="TrialSerialNumber">911987057659283838047464</Data>
```

может быть вложен сколько угодно раз и перенесен в другой родительский узел(parent), а локатор не поменяется.

Можно использовать и вот этот локатор:

```
//Other[@adobeCode='V7{}Photoshop-19-Win-GM']/child::Data[@key='TrialSerialNumber']
```

но тогда этот узел нельзя переносить из родительского узла:

```
<Other adobeCode="V7{}Photoshop-19-Win-GM">
```

Я бы использовал вот такой вариант программы:

```
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class XPathTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("D:\\programmer\\application.xml"))
        {
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            String data = xPath.evaluate("//Data[@key='TrialSerialNumber']", new InputSource(fileReader));
            System.out.println(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Только не понятно, почему атрибут `key=TrialSerialNumber` является уникальным?

Answer (score 0):

Есть множество способов это сделать. Например если у вас есть DTD или схема документа XML, то вы можете загрузить все содержимое в `Document` и испольбзовать его для поиска нужонго элемента.

Или же вы можете распарсить XML при помощи SAX. Тогда вам надо следить за каждым появлением такого элемента в обработчике.

Или же вы можете просканировать файл на наличие требуемого значения в строке

```
String n = s.replaceFirst("<Data.*key=\"TrialSerialNumber\".*>(.*)</Data>", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот регуляркой (PCRE):

```
<Data.*key="TrialSerialNumber".*>\K\d*(?=<\/Data>)
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5bbqo

> <Data
> key="TrialSerialNumber">**911987057659283838047464**</Data>
>
> <Data key="TrialSerialNumber">**123**</Data>
>
> <Data key="TrialSerialNumber" k=v>**123**</Data>
>
> <Data key="42" k=v>123</Data>